# struts.ui.theme disables the label of s:select

Tags: struts2

I am using `struts.ui.theme = simple` and it appears to disable the `label` attribute of `s:select` tag.

Is there any way to use the struts theme without disabling the label attribute?

Comment: Read about themes: http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/themes-and-templates.html.

Answer (score 0):

For perticular page try this

```
<s:set name="theme" value="'simple'" scope="page" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use theme for that particular element.

```
<s:select theme="xhtml" .../>
```